# setTimeout not working with Angular5

Tags: javascript, angular5

**this.fetchRequests(this) gets executed as soon as the view is initialized instead of waiting for 20 seconds.**

I am aware in the older versions we have to use the wrapper but in the new versions those are not required I guess. Any help on this would be helpful.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.fetchRequests(this);
    }), 10000;
}
```

Comment: Your closing `)` is too early. It should instead be *after* `1000`.

Comment: Have you tried this code without having typographical errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you write the wrong syntax 
this code

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    this.fetchRequests(this);
}), 10000;
```

should be like this

```
setTimeout(()=>{ this.fetchRequests(this); },1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in `zone.run()`.

First, import `NgZone` from `@angular/core`, and inject it into your component.

Then, modify your ngAfterViewInit to look like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.fetchRequests(this);
        }, 10000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @wilsonhobbs. This worked but I found the actual problem to be a silly syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. If you want it to work with change detection, though, this is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

your syntax is wrong

two syntax's are here for function  one which is blow new one

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    this.fetchRequests(this); 
},1000);
```

and second below syntax is old one you can use both of them

```
setTimeout(function(){
        this.fetchRequests(this); 
},1000);
```

both are functional in Angular 9-  Typescript and Nodejs  and latest javascript version by now